# Twillio issue when sending messages:

Tags: tags, twilio

I am trying to find a solution for this issue:

> Uncaught PHP Exception Services_Twilio_RestException: "Authenticate"
>   at /var/www/test/vendor/twilio/sdk/Services/Twilio.php line 297
>   {"exception":"[object] (Services_Twilio_RestException(code: 20003):
>   Authenticate at
>   /var/www/banjo-api/vendor/twilio/sdk/Services/Twilio.php:297)"}

I read some articles here but my sid and authToken for my twillio account are correctly and I don't have any idea how to fix it. Does anybody knows why this issue appears.

I can say that my account is trial

Thank you in advance, Flavius

**[edit]**: code from comment

```
["version:protected"]=> string(10) "2010-04-01"
$number_code = mt_rand(Authorize::MIN_NUMBER, Authorize::MAX_NUMBER);
$twilioManager = $this->container->get('twilio.api');
$twilioManager->account->messages->sendMessage(Authorize::TW‌​ILIO_FROM_NUMBER, '+' . $user->getUsername(), Authorize::MESSAGE_CODE . $number_code);
```

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using? Could you post the relevant part of your code?

Comment: ["version:protected"]=>
  string(10) "2010-04-01"                                                               $number_code = mt_rand(Authorize::MIN_NUMBER, Authorize::MAX_NUMBER);                                                         $twilioManager = $this->container->get('twilio.api');
$twilioManager->account->messages->sendMessage(Authorize::TWILIO_FROM_NUMBER, '+' . $user->getUsername(), Authorize::MESSAGE_CODE . $number_code);

Comment: I notice that i hadn't this probleme before. It passed 3 months after I create my twillio account and it is a free version? It is possible that the problem appears because i have a free version of twillio?

Comment: How are you setting your Account Sid and Auth Token?

Comment: i install and configure this bundle VreshTwilioBundle() and put after in config.yml   the following:                                                                                                                    vresh_twilio:
    sid: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    authToken: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    retryAttempts: 1

Comment: Have you put your `sid` and `authToken` in quotes? For example: `sid: 'XXXXXXXX'` and `authToken: 'YYYYYYYY'`

Comment: yes and it doesn't work

Comment: Did this work before and has just stopped working? Or has it never worked?

Comment: Yes it worked for 3 month and after that I got this issue with authentication. It is possible that this problem appear because I have a trial twillio account?

Comment: I would contact Twilio support and make sure your account is still active.

Comment: The problem was the trial version of my twillio account and probably the account did not remain active